# Problema con la terminal cmd luego de hacer npm start

Tags: reactjs, cmd, npm

Estoy empezando con React y al momento de hacer npm start, se me abre la app en el localhost, hasta ahí genial, el problema es que la cmd (o la terminal que este usando en ese momento) se me queda como congelada y no puedo seguir escribiendo nada. ¿cómo se puede destrabar y continuar escribiendo?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Te explico, en la terminal es como una personita que solo puede hacer una cosa a la vez (monoproceso). Es decir si estoy ejecutando npm start esta haciendo eso y no me dejara hacer mas. es completamente normal. si queres colocar otro comando u otra cosa tenes 2 opciones:

- Cerrar el proceso usando este comando en la terminal o consola

> ctrl + c

- Abrir una nueva terminal y dejar que la otra haga su trabajo.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero ayúdanos a responder preguntas cumplan con lo definido en el [help], especificamente [ask], te sugerimos revisa [ask], Saludos.